# How does iptables filtering in the FORWARD or INPUT chain interact with NAT?

Tags: iptables, firewall, nat

[This](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-9.html) page seems to suggest that, if there is a rule in the `PREROUTING` chain of the `nat` table that translates destination `1.2.3.4:80` to `10.1.1.1:8080`, then the rules in the `INPUT` and `FORWARD` chain should match on `10.1.1.1:8080`, not `1.2.3.4:80`.

What if one wants to implement an order of operation more like what's outlined [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/network-address-translation-nat/6209-5.html)? That is, how do you perform filtering on characteristics of packets before NAT?

One possibility seems to be using the `PREROUTING` chain of the `raw` table. The issue is that conntrack isn't available in `raw/PREROUTING` (see note 1), and e.g. a non-initial UDP fragment will not be related to the initial fragment and will produce unexpected matches.

Please let me know if I've described the dilemma clearly, and whether there's any workaround.

Note 1:
Correct me if I'm wrong, but when I tried to use conntrack in `raw/PREROUTING`, all initial SYN packets were marked "`INVALID`" rather than "`NEW`". It also seems like, in the Netfilter flowchart, "conntrack" is after `raw/PREROUTING`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need any `raw/PREROUTING` rules. You can use the `conntrack` match to filter the packets by original (before translation) destination/source address/port number. The `conntrack` is a successor of the older `state` match. It can check various additional metadata, related with `conntrack entry` (and NAT).

Couple of examples:

```
# allow any port-forwarded packets
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT

# check the original destination address of DNATed packets
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT --ctorigdstport 80 --ctorigdst X.X.X.X --ctdir ORIGINAL -j ACCEPT
```

For more details check the output of `iptables -m conntrack --help` and `man iptables-extensions`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netfilter#/media/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg) describes the relations between the different hooks seeing a packet. Here's a smaller part of it:

[image: Packet flow in Netfilter and General Networking]

So if you want to interact *statefully* with packets *before* nat, the logical choice is `mangle/PREROUTING`: the *conntrack* hook already tracked the packet: it won't get an INVALID state, but *nat* still didn't happen.

Just remember that iptables' *nat* sees only the first packet and then everything else is handled directly by *conntrack*, still happening at the same place: between `mangle/PREROUTING` and the routing decision.

The other method is described in Anton Danilov's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1046382/217515): by querying *conntrack* to check the former address from its lookup table.